# Does an elasticsearch simple_query_string query use dis_max or bool to combine queries when multiple fields are specified?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently using a `query_string` query with multiple `fields` and `"use_dis_max": false`. I'm considering switching to a `simple_query_string` query, which also allows multiple `fields`. However, the [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) don't mention a `use_dis_max` parameter for `simple_query_string`, and don't explain how queries over multiple fields are combined. Does a multi-field `simple_query_string` query combine queries using `bool` or `dis_max`? Is there a way to specify one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, there is no mention of it in the documents but it constructs a bool query.
Simple query string  is implemented using [SimpleQueryParser](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-queryparser/4.7.0/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/simple/SimpleQueryParser.java#514) of Lucene.
Looking at the code it seems like it is a boolean query.

You can confirm this by running a simple_query_string query with the explain flag to true something on these lines

```
{
    "explain": true, 
      "_source" :["doc_id"],
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "fields" :<field_list>,
            "query" : <token>
        }
    }
}
```

In the explain portion of the response we see a sum_of instead of a max_of which would show up in dis_max showing it is a boolean query.
There is no way to set the dis_max flag in simple_query_string.

Comment: Won't the query behave same as dis_max if we specify "default_operator": "and"?

Comment: they are quite different. Consider you have a search query : "cat" and the fields you are searching against are  ["feline_field" , "mammal_field"] a `dis_max` would return  the `max (match score on feline_field, match_score on mammal_field)`  . A  default operator `and` on the other hand  ensures that every query token should   match at least one field in the list and if a token matches multiple fields  it would sum the score.For the above example it would be `sum(match score on feline_field, match_score on mammal_field)`